# Change Adobe Reader's default program for e-mail links

Tags: email, thunderbird, adobe-reader, mailto

When I click an e-mail address in Adobe Reader X, an Outlook e-mail window opens, even though Thunderbird is my standard e-mail client and assigned to the `mailto:` protocol.

**How can I make Adobe Reader X open e-mail links in Thunderbird?**

I'm using Windows 7. [*How to Change the Email Client in Adobe Reader*](http://www.ehow.com/how_8315945_change-email-client-adobe-reader.html) doesn't seem to apply to this version of Adobe Reader, I don't see the drop-down menu of step 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, for some reason there were two different settings, which were called depending on the current user context:

1. start regedit,
2. find your way to

   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command`
3. check if it's the same value as in

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Thunderbird.Url.mailto\shell\open\command`
4. check if it's the same value as in 
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command`

Please note:

- Presumably the value should be something like `"C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -osint -compose "%1"`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\‌​‌​mailto\UserChoice`
  should be something like Progid `Thunderbird.Url.mailto`

Comment: Thanks so much for digging through the registry, this had really been bugging me for a while `:)`

Comment: After updating to Adobe Reader 11, I seem to have the same issue, even though all the registry entries you mention have the correct values. Any ideas?

Comment: The first answer worked with Adobe Reader XI ver. 11.0.06. I suggest copying the Thunderbird value the first time you find it to avoid backtracking. I had to change the value in the third LOCAL MACHINE string.

Answer (score 3):

I did all of the above but it did not work, but I found [another solution](http://i.org.helsinki.fi/lassial/guides/windows/Acrobat_Thunderbird_issues_in_).

1. Go to *Control Panel ⇨ All Control Panel Items ⇨ Default Programs*
2. Select *Set Program Access and Computer Defaults* (**not** *Set Your Default Programs*)
3. Choose *Custom*
4. Set *Email program* (not current program) to be Thunderbird

Step two was the tricky part.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds interesting and plausible, but I can't test it, since the accepted answer had already solved my problem. It'll certainly be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Windows if you are getting as far as not seeing the dropdown.  Adobe Reader (both 9 and 10) respects the Windows system settings for default clients.

When you go to `Edit / Preferences / Internet / Internet Settings` it is just opening the Windows internet settings dialog.  Reader does not have one of its own.

The linked article is referring to Windows XP, where the Programs tab shows the dropdowns for each application type.  Under Windows 7 this moved to the `Set Programs` button at the bottom of the tab in the Internet Programs section.

This will take you to the `Default Programs` settings page.  Click `Set Your Default Programs`.  In the list, choose Thunderbird, then click `Set this program as default`.  This will make sure Thunderbird is selected for email in all cases where an email client can be invoked, not just when a `mailto:` link is clicked.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Unfortunately, this setting had already been set, i.e. Thunderbird had already had all the standards. I ensured it was set and tried again, but the compose window opened in Outlook again.

Comment: Does it do the same if you do Send To Email in something like Word?

Comment: No, in Word or Firefox, a Thunderbird compose window opens. Adobe Reader is the only program in which I've encountered this behavior.

Comment: Why are adobe products so stupid when it comes to things like this.  It seems to be ignoring the system setting, is this your machine or a work machine with a standard build?

Comment: It's my personal, own laptop.

Comment: Ok, I am out of ideas - it isn't working as it should, and is likely a bug or configuration issue where Adobe is incorrectly reading the results it gets from the system.  If an uninstall-reinstall of X doesn't fix it, I would suggest using one of the lightweight and faster alternatives to Reader (though I appreciate this might mean missing functionality that you need; some of them are pretty full featured though).

Comment: I uninstalled, cleaned the registry and temporary data with CCleaner, downloaded the latest installer, reinstalled -- still the same problem. Thanks for your help, still.